# iOS7 UitableView delayContent Touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I Have a UITableView with my own UITableViewcell implementation to handle touches for cell.
So I have already enabled delayContentTouches property so that touch methods doesn't get affected by normal scrolls.
But with iOS7 it directly goes to touch began method without any delay.
Is there a way to stop this, i just want to scroll the table as usual and is user keep his finger for some time to go to touchBegan method. (simply iOS to identify is this a scroll or not as it worked in iOS 6 and older versions)

Thanks in advanced..

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that delays touches?